# Coreplot animations with identifier

Tags: ios, animation, core-plot

I am trying to perform multiple animations in coreplot.
To run first animation I've used:

```
 [CPTAnimation animate:plotSpace
                 property:@"xRange"
            fromPlotRange:oldXrange
              toPlotRange:newxRange
                 duration:1.0
                withDelay:0
           animationCurve:CPTAnimationCurveCubicInOut
                 delegate:self];
```

and implemented `CPTAnimationDelegate`:

```
-(void)animationDidFinish:(nonnull CPTAnimationOperation *)operation {
    CPTPlotRange *newxRange = [CPTPlotRange
                               plotRangeWithLocation:@500
                               length:@100];

    [self performSecondAnimationWithnewXRange:newXrange];}
```

I want, however, to run multiple animations using identifier. I've tried creatingPTAnimationOperation, but don't know how to fire it:

```
CPTAnimationOperation* animation1 = [[CPTAnimationOperation alloc] init];
CPTAnimationPeriod *period = [CPTAnimationPeriod periodWithStartPlotRange:plotSpace.xRange
                                                                         endPlotRange:newxRange
                                                                             duration:3.0
                                                                            withDelay:0.0];
animation1.identifier = @"animation1ID";
animation1.period = period;
```

How do I actually start the animation, so in delegate I could check it's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the second animation the same way you did for the first one. Pass `nil` for the start value to have the animation begin from the current value of the property. The `+animate:property:…` methods all return the `CPTAnimationOperation` so you can set the `identifier` or have a reference if you might want to cancel it early.

Comment: As always, Eric's answers are the best :D Worked like a charm.